# Why is $L^2$ norm of the gradient called kinetic energy?

Tags: energy, notation

I'm reading Lieb-Loss's book 'Analysis', chapter 7. The authors refer to the following integral:

$$\tag{1} \lVert \nabla f\rVert_2^2=\int_{\Omega}\lvert \nabla f(x)\rvert^2\, d^nx $$

as the *kinetic energy* (see pag. 172), without explanation. To what physical system are they referring to? My intuitions says that (1) would be more appropriately called *potential* energy, as we have discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16755/3255).

---

(Note: In a later paragraph the authors introduce a magnetic potential $\mathbf{A}$ and the so-called *covariant derivative* $\nabla+i\mathbf{A}$, remarking that after this introduction the kinetic energy integral must be replaced with

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\lvert (\nabla + i \mathbf{A})f(x)\rvert^2\, d^n x.$$

This induces me to think that they take as a model some kind of electromagnetic system.)

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: In quantum mechanics, the gradient operator represents momentum (to within a constant factor).  That is why they would call the square of the gradient the kinetic energy (momentum squared, to within a constant factor).  That is quite general and not confined to any particular system.  But yes, the vector potential is added to deal with the electromagnetic field.

Comment: @Greg P,  Wouldn't the kinetic energy be proportional to the expectation value of the Laplacian operator? I was thinking of exactly what you have said, but was unsure since the OP has a different expression.

Comment: @Vijay: integrate by parts, then you see that the expectation value of the (negative) Laplacian operator is precisely the $L^2$ norm of the gradient.

Comment: @Willie Wong, Yes I can see that. But that sort of assumes that $f(x)$ or $\nabla f(x)$ vanishes on the boundary. If this is indeed what the OP had in mind, then fine.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily quantum mechanical. This term is called kinetic energy in every fluid dynamics book as well.

Comment: @VijayMurthy: The books does not make that assumption explictly, in fact. But it might be that it was in the back of the authors's minds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Greg P mentions in a comment, this terminology is inspired by [quantum mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics).

1. $f(x)$ plays the role of the [wave function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function) $\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle$ in the position space representation.
2. The conjugate/canonical momentum operator $\hat{\bf p}$ is replaced by $\frac{\hbar}{i}{\bf \nabla}$ in the Schrödinger representation.
3. The [kinetic/mechanical momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_momentum) operator $m\hat{\bf v}$ is replaced by $\hat{\bf p}+{\bf A}$ (if we absorb certain constants, such as the charge of the particles, into the definition of the magnetic potential ${\bf A}$.)
4. The expectation value $\langle\psi| \hat{K}|\psi\rangle$ of the non-relativistic kinetic energy operator $\hat{K}=\frac{m}{2}\hat{\bf v}^2$ is 
   $$\langle\psi| \hat{K}|\psi\rangle
   ~=~\frac{m}{2} \int d^n x~ |\hat{\bf v}\psi(x)|^2
   ~=~\frac{1}{2m} \int d^n x~ |(\hbar{\bf \nabla}-i{\bf A})\psi(x)|^2.  $$