# Intuitively proof that intensity of a wave is proportional to the square of its amplitude

Tags: energy, waves

Firstly I would like to know if this is valid for every kind of wave, or are there any conditions/exceptions where this is not valid.

But the main question is, is it possible to prove this fact for a general wave intuitively, rather than taking specific waves and deriving equations and showing it?

Comment: This question is only answerable if you can provide a definition of "intensity" that holds for every wave.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I= power transferred per unit area

Comment: @gpuguy: "I = power transferred per unit area"... You need to put that in your original question.

Comment: It's a good question, but already answered elsewhere http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16755/