# Symbol in energy formula vs amplitude

Tags: waves, notation

Can someone tell me what does the symbol mean in the formula for energy compared to amplitude?  Looks like a partial infinity sign,  almost like a fish symbol.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comment, the "fish" is the [mathematical symbol for "proportional to"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)#Symbols). In the case of the [amplitude and energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16755/why-is-energy-in-a-wave-proportional-to-amplitude-squared),
$$
E\propto A^2
$$
means that
$$
E=CA^2
$$
for some constant $C$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that "fish" refers to $\propto$. It is means "proportional to". Since @Kyle Kanos has provided useful links about this, I won't repeat them.

But I want to add a useful tool for checking unfamilar symbols: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

You can draw the symbol and get its latex code, and then it's easy to find its meaning (usually the latex command name itself is enough).